How are people buying even faser than the owner of the CA?
What are the steps these people take that allow them to purchase a token faster than the owner of the CA? They purchase in split seconds.
What are the RPC configurations and generally actions that they take that allows this?
Would love to understand the complexity of it.
Thanks.
